# Incorrect dipslay of size from Text Swatch attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, size

we are having problem with correct display size from Text Swatch attribute. If the size is to long, text is displaced to next line with one line space. For example "30 - 34 cm". It does not matter if I set it as "30-34cm" or 30-34 cm, it is always divided into two lines with one line space. Any ideas how to fix that?

[image]
[image]